# substring in awk using gsub regular expression

Tags: awk

The requirement is very simple i feel.

Input string format:

```
DTC_SubrProfile_20141205230707.unl
```

Required output format:

```
SubrProfile
```

Meaning, "DTC_" "_20141205230707.unl" should be removed from the input string.

Is there possible way we can achieve it using awk gsub?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. The requirement for this specific case is very simple but you need to make it clear what the general pattern is, for example "extract the part between the first and second _". If you think it's simple, have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: Please update your question by editing it, rather than using the comments beneath the answer that you have received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through sed,

```
$ echo 'DTC_SubrProfile_20141205230707.unl' | sed 's/^[^_]*_\|_.*//g'
SubrProfile
```

Through awk,

```
$ echo 'DTC_SubrProfile_20141205230707.unl' | awk '{gsub(/^[^_]*_|_.*/,"")}1'
SubrProfile
```

The above commands would remove all the characters from the start to the first underscore and then it removes from the `_` upto the last from the remaining string.

```
$ echo 'DTC_SubrProfile_20141205230707.unl' | awk -F'_' '{print $2}'
SubrProfile
```

The above awk would print the second column according to the input Field Separator `_`

Comment: Why would you use gsub to extract a field like that?

Comment: I think op wants to use gsub.

Comment: @TomFenech,  I have master file having the format "SubrProfile", "CustProfile" etc. Whenever new files appear like "DTC_SubrProfile_20140101000000.unl", "DTN_SubrProfile_20140101000000.unl"  I need to match whether all the new files match the pattern of master file or not.

Comment: Perhaps so but it seems like a pretty arbitrary requirement. Setting `IFS` using `-F` as you have done is the best way to go.

Comment: @TomFenech, no the question still remains the same. I would use this small substitution inside the script.

Comment: @AvinashRaj what if the filename consists of underscore ?  something like DTC_AccountProfile_dual_20140101000000.unl. So, regexp should be like until it finds a number?

Comment: 1) "My car won't start, how do I start it?" 2) "Jump start it" 3) "Thanks, but it's actually horse". Sigh...

Comment: @YETISHKODAVA use grep `grep -oP '[^_]*(?=_\d+)' file`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thanks. I used this awk '{gsub(/^[^_]*_|[0-9].*/,"")}1'. Would give me an extra "_" at the end. Never mind, would put an underscore in the config file. Cheers.

Comment: @EdMorton Yes, i understand the question wasn't coveyed clearly. Agree with Tom as well. Had less time to fix this thing. Sorry guys. Expect your expertise to help my future questions. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

by cut

```
echo "DTC_SubrProfile_20141205230707.unl"|cut -d _ -f2
```